# Getting negative value in variance formula calculation

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, variance, multinomial-coefficients

I am interested in calculating variance formula for this random variable:
$$
F=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \left ( \frac{f_i}{n} - w_i \right )^{2}
$$

Let me give you some description about the experimental situation. Let us assume that we performed an experiment and that we have $n$ data values bounded in the interval $(x_\text{min},x_\text{max})$. Now we divide that interval into $N$ bins and calculate frequencies for each bin $f_i$ for that data set. Here $w_i$ is the expected relative frequency for the $i^\text{th}$ bin.

This is the first step of my calculations:
\begin{align}
V(n)
&= Var\left [ F \right ] \\
&= Var\left [ \sum_{i=1}^{N}\left ( \frac{f_i}{n}-w_i \right )^{2} \right ] \\
&= E\left [ \left ( \sum_{i=1}^{N}\left ( \frac{f_i}{n}-w_i \right )^{2} \right )^2 \right ]-\left ( E\left [ \left ( \sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{f_i}{n}-w_i \right )^{2} \right ] \right )^{2} \\
&= E\left [ \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}\left ( \frac{f_i}{n}-w_i \right )^{2}\left ( \frac{f_j}{n}-w_j \right )^{2} \right ]-\left ( E\left [ F(n) \right ] \right )^{2} \\
&= \sum_{i=1,j=1}^{N,N}E\left [ \left ( \frac{f_i}{n}-w_i \right )^{2}\left ( \frac{f_j}{n}-w_j \right )^{2} \right ]-\left ( E\left [ F(n) \right ] \right )^{2}
\end{align}
I have calculated $E[F]$ separately,
$$
E\left [ F \right ]=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left ( w_i-w_i^{2} \right ) \;,
$$
and this formula gives correct results consistent with simulation results.

Now,
\begin{align}
\left ( \frac{f_i}{n}-w_i \right )^{2}\left ( \frac{f_j}{n}-w_j \right )^{2}
&= \frac{f_i^{2}f_j^{2}}{n^{4}}-\frac{2w_jf_i^{2}f_j}{n^{3}} \\
&+ \frac{w_j^{2}f_i^{2}}{n^{2}}-\frac{2w_if_if_j^{2}}{n^3} \\
&+ \frac{4w_iw_jf_if_j}{n^2}-\frac{2w_iw_j^{2}f_i}{n} \\
&+ \frac{w_i^2f_j^2}{n^2}-\frac{2w_i^2w_jf_j}{n}+w_i^2w_j^2
\end{align}

So,
\begin{align}
V(n)
&= \frac{1}{n^4}\sum_{i,j}^{.} E[f_i^2f_j^2]-\frac{2}{n^3}\sum_{i,j}^{.}w_jE[f_i^2f_j] \\
&+ \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i,j}^{.}w_j^2E[f_i^2]-\frac{2}{n^3}\sum_{i,j}^{.}w_iE[f_if_j^2] \\
&+ \frac{4}{n^2}\sum_{i,j}^{.}w_iw_jE[f_if_j]-\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i,j}^{.}w_iw_j^2E[f_i] \\
&+ \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i,j}^{.}w_i^2E[f_j^2]-\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i,j}^{.}w_i^2w_jE[f_j] \\
&+ \sum_{i,j}^{.}w_i^2w_j^2-\frac{1}{n^2}\left [ \sum_{i}^{.}(w_i-w_i^2) \right ]^2
\end{align}

From the binomial distribution we know that $E(f_i)=nw_i$ and $E(f_i^2)=n(n-1)w_i^2+nw_i$, and from the multinomial distribution we can calculate
\begin{align}
E(f_if_j) &= n(n-1)w_iw_j \\
E(f_i^{2}f_j) &= n(n-1)(n-2)w_i^{2}w_j+n(n-1)w_iw_j \\
E(f_if_j^{2}) &= n(n-1)(n-2)w_iw_j^{2}+n(n-1)w_iw_j \\
E(f_i^{2}f_j^{2}) &= n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)w_i^{2}w_j^{2}+n(n-1)(n-2)w_i^{2}w_j \\
&+ n(n-1)(n-2)w_iw_j^{2}+n(n-1)w_iw_j
\end{align}

Please refer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363731/calculation-of-covariances-covx-i2-x-j-and-covx-i2-x-j2-for-mul) for further clarification of above results.

If I put all the values into the equation of $V(n)$, I get this [I have checked the calculations between the above step of the $V(n)$ formula and the below step, and I am sure that there is no mistake]:
\begin{align}
V(n)
&= \left ( \frac{3}{n^2} -\frac{6}{n^3}\right )\sum_{i,j}^{.}w_i^2w_j^2+\left ( \frac{4}{n^3}-\frac{2}{n^2} \right )\sum_{i,j}^{.}w_iw_j^2 \\
&+ \left ( \frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^3} \right )\sum_{i,j}^{.} w_iw_j-\frac{1}{n^2}\left [ \sum_{i}^{.}\left ( w_i-w_i^2 \right ) \right ]^2
\end{align}

In more simplified form this will be,
$$
V(n)
= \left ( \frac{2}{n^2} -\frac{6}{n^3}\right )\sum_{i,j}^{.}w_i^2w_j^2+\left ( \frac{4}{n^3} \right )\sum_{i,j}^{.}w_iw_j^2 - \left ( \frac{1}{n^3} \right )\sum_{i,j}^{.} w_iw_j
$$

The problem is, when I put ${w_i}$ values from my simulation, I get negative values of the variance, because the final formula turns out to be
$$
V(n)=\frac{1.2209 \times 10^{-6}}{n^2}-\frac{0.9960}{n^3} \;.
$$
But variance can't be negative, because from the simple definition, we know that it is a weighted sum of $(x-\bar{x})^2$. I think I made some trivial mistake. Also, I checked the steps of my calculations many times, and I could not find any error.

Here, $N=5,000$ and the maximum value of $w_i$ is in the order $10^{-2}$.

***Some interesting observations*::**

When I derived the formula for $N=10$ ($i.e.$ for 10 bins) then,

$$
V(n)=\frac{0.4185}{n^2}-\frac{0.4257}{n^3}
$$

and this formula totally matches with experimental results.

If I denote $A=\sum_{i,j}^{.}w_i^2w_j^2$; $B=\sum_{i,j}^{.}w_i^2w_j$; $C=\sum_{i,j}^{.}w_iw_j$; $D=\sum_{i,j}^{.} w_i^2$; $E=\sum_{i,j}^{.} w_i$ then values of those quantities for number of bins,=10,5000,10000,20000 are attached here under,

[image: Values of A,B,C,D,E]

As you can see when number of bin increases A,B,D all becomes negligible with respect to C and E. This is basically main reason of getting negative value in variance formula.

I will be grateful if someone will provide a satisfactory answer.

Comment: it can be due to programming error in calculation of $\sum_{i,j}^{.}w_iw_j$ etc.... here one has to remember that $\sum_{i=0}^{N} w_i=1.0$  ... hence for  N=5,000 most of the $w_i$'s become very small... still I can't figure out exactly where I make mistake....

Answer (score 0):

The random variable $F$  (the notation $F(n)$ doesn't make sense) is defined using a summation on $N$ "$f_i$" samples. To evaluate the mean and variance of $F$, you will need a summation on $M$ "$F_j$" samples, i.e. $NM$ samples of $f_{ij}$ in total. This does not appear in your computation.

Comment: In the above question all summation signs are for summation over all possible bins... Idea of this calculation is this:: since we don't have knowledge about distribution of this $(\frac{f_i}{n}-w_i)^{2}$ RVs hence at first I simplified the formula in such a way that I will have deal with only ${f_i}$ RVs. Now we know that all $[f_i]$ RVs will be multinomially distributed. Hence I use known techniques (moment generating function) to calculate $E(f_if_j)$ etc. to get final form.

Comment: Well I am from physics background and I can be terribly wrong about some usual concepts. But I think F(n) notation do make sense. Its like I have a population which contain "infinite" amount of data and each time I am drawing a random sample of size n (means that random data set will contain n data values). Then F random variable is defined as "L2 measure of risk function" (here my terminology can be very non-mathematical). In other words if I have large n then "mismatch between theoretical result and experimental result" (F) will be less.

Comment: In that sense I tried to mean that F random variable will depend on sample size.

Comment: Although I do agree that since F is a random variable and hence it can't be function of anything. In other words, only a deterministic quantity can be function of something. For example I can write V (variance of F) as function of n because mean,variance,etc. are deterministic quantities.

Comment: "Summation on M "$F_j$" samples" is implicitly taken through derivation of formulas $E(f_if_j)$ etc.